# There is any way to see the subroutine local variables values and who actually access them?

Tags: assembly, stack-variables, tracing, local-variables

I know that it exists gdb, but i'm talking about windows, i would like know if there is any way to see who access to current stackframe of a specified variable on an X subroutine...

i've tried using CE using the "Find out what accesses this address" option through the stackframe but the stackframe logically it's dynamic then i get over 2000 registers...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Can you post how you do it in gdb?

Comment: @Paweł Łukasik I'm not on linux, but i'm looking something like that for windows... meanwhile i'm using breakpoints and capturing on an X time the stackframe activity...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a debugger with access to symbols, then you can run to the start of the function, and then place watches on the symbol names.

In the absence of a debugger, if you can hook the function itself, then one way to do it is this:

- save the original few bytes in the routine, and install a hook;
- resume execution;
- when your hook code gains control, create a hardware breakpoint on the address(es) of interest, and an exception handler to receive notifications on access;
- set the stack parameters, etc, appropriate to call the original function at the point after your hook code (e.g. EIP+5).  Calling the function manually in this way will simplify the next step.
- when the function returns, remove the hardware breakpoint, clean the stack to remove the original invocation, and return to the caller.

Comment: I'm doing something like that, but without an `VEH`, i'm tracing the stackpointer, so if i have an local variable like `[esp+0x88]` then i trace the total address on an X time with breakpoints into of subroutine logically, anyway i will try your way... thanks you.